# Command for mp a role - Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want I i want to make an command that mp a role when you send a message such as "@role, message"

Here is my code :

```
@bot.command()
async def DM(ctx, role : discord.Role.members, content):  
    channel = await role.create_dm()
    await channel.send(content)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you define MP? Are you trying to dm all members with a role?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean by mp you mean *mass ping*. Regardless to have a command like this would almost certainly be painfully ratelimited (10 user dms per 10 seconds), but let's say hypothetically you don't care, this is how I would approach it

(this requires the members intent)

```py
@bot.command()
async def DM(ctx, role : discord.Role.members, content):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            channel = await member.create_dm()
            await channel.send(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you for your help! But from my side it seems that the code doesn't work ^^

Besides this order will not be used to harass people lol Just to send a newspaper when these people will have chosen a role beforehand

The Error :
[image: The Error]